# Swift - JSON String printing \n instead of new line

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, logging

I wonder if there is any way to print exact JSON string in pretty format while logging. I was printing a http request header fields like,

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: .prettyPrinted)
let jsonString = String(bytes: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
MyLogUtil.logVerbose(message: "\(String(describing: jsonString))")
```

But instead of printing expected logs like below,

```
{
   "user": {
       name: "Test",
       age: "30"
    }
}
```

Its printing something like,

```
{\n"user": {\nname: "Test",\n\nage: "30"\n}\n}\n
```

How to get rid of this issue?

**EDIT:**
@AwaisFayyaz

```
func requestTest() -> Void {

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!) { (data, response, error) in

            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String: Any]
                if let userDict = json["user"] as? NSDictionary {
                    print(userDict)
                }
            }
            catch let error as NSError {

                print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Above code got crashed!

[image]

Comment: kkkk jsonString it is already an optional `String?`. All you need to do is to unwrap your optional. `if let jsonString = ...`. You probably will never need to use `String(describing:)` method even if Xcode suggests you should. Btw using a string interpolation to display a string is pointless. Just print your jsonString after unwrapping it. `print(jsonString)` or in your case`MyLogUtil.logVerbose(message: jsonString)`

Comment: Have you tried `.sortedKeys` instead of `.prettyPrinted`? It looks like the white space from `prettyPrinted` could be causing the issue.

Comment: @Jake didn't work

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for suggestion but what about the format error, it still prints '\n\n' stuffs in log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is your input string that you want to print in pretty format. Then

```
let str = "{\"user\":{\"name\":\"Test\",\"age\":\"30\"} }"
```

Then use

```
let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

do {
  let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]

  if let userDict = json["user"] as? NSDictionary {
    print(userDict)
  }


} catch let error as NSError {
  print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

I have implemented the code. See the console output in the image

[image]

@Answer to **Edit**

Your code is crashing because JSON is returning An Array and you are **force** casting as **[String: Any]** (not possible). Instead cast it as **NSArray**

use the following code snippet in this case

func requestTest() -> Void {

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!) { (data, response, error) in

  do {
    //cast it as Array
    let usersArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! NSArray
    for userDictAny in usersArray {
      //cast the type of userDictAny to NSDictionary
      guard let userDict = userDictAny as? NSDictionary else {
        print("Error. Count not cast as NSDictionary. Going to return")
        return
      }
      print("\n\n\(userDict)\n\n")
      //additionaly, if you want to get value of individual fields from userDict
      if let userId = userDict["userId"] as? Int64 {
        print("Value of userID \(userId)")
      }
      //in the same way get more values if you want from userDict

    }


  }
  catch let error as NSError {

    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
}
task.resume()
}
```

Note that original ordering of data will not be preserved because it is a dictionary. But you can see your output in nice format

**Output Snapshot of running code**
[image: output for updated code]

Comment: you mean order will not be preserved ?

Comment: @Sazzad Hissain Khan. what is the your input json string that you want to print  ?

Comment: I dint give down vote, but your solution still don't work. same thing when printing.

Comment: I have implemented my solution on a sample string and is working fine. also incuded screen shots in my answer. 
Can you give me the input json string that you are trying to print in pretty format.?

Comment: screenshots showing fine but actual logs are not same as in the screen. I will share soon.

Comment: Waiting... and you did not give me the input string that you are trying to print in pretty format. ?

Comment: @Sazzad Please see the update answer. Let me know if there is any issue